# Create Hive Table with Description

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Where should table descriptions be added when creating tables in Hive?

> Table name: "Orders"
>
> Table Description: "Orders from Vendor ABC."

Answer (score 5):

You should use **[COMMENT table_comment]** keyword in the command.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (id String, name String) COMMENT 'Orders from Vendor ABC.' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

You can find details [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable)